# Accept every alert along the way

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I am currently automating tests with Selenium/C#/SpecFlow.

In our application we are experiencing some unexpected and expected alerts. Now these alerts are not crucial and non-blocking for any of our tests. These are known environment issues.

What I want to achieve is, throughout every test, I want Selenium to accept any alert at any point. Is there a way to define this at the beginning of the test so whenever there is an alert, it gets accepted?

Thanks in advance!
Anand

Comment: Try checking the desired capability of Selenium , you may be able to set the Accept the Alert as true. Worth checking it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps setting the desired capabilities for your `WebDriver` will help. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772793/org-openqa-selenium-unhandledalertexception-unexpected-alert-open) post.