# Closing an alert with Selenium WebDriverJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been struggling trying to close an alert the browser opens only with a specific patterns I don't control, so I need a piece of code that detects and closes the alert to be able to continue navigating the web and not stopping the execution.

I tried several ways of dealing with the alert, but none of them has been successful for the moment:

Here are some of the examples I've been working with:

1:

```
driver.wait(driver.switchTo().activeElement().then(
  function() {
    console.log("alert detected");
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
  },
  function() {
    console.log("no alert detected");
  }
), 1000);
```

2:

```
  driver.wait(driver.switchTo().alert().accept()
        .then(null, function(err)
        {
            console.log("ERROR ALERT");
            console.log(err);
            console.log("ERROR NAME");
            console.log(err.name);
        }), 1000);
```

3: Inject this piece of code trying to overwrite the alert of the browser to make it to not appear:

```
  driver.executeScript('alert = function(){};');
```

Basically these three are the main workarounds I've been struggling with, but for the moment none seems to work properly.

Comment: Which webdriver do you use? (firefox, chrome, ghostdriver...etc)  In addition, the above method `switchTo()` works with Firefox and even not handling the issue still let the navigation pursues.

Comment: I am using chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what finally worked to close all the emerging alert/confirms throughout the navigation between all pages:

```
    driver.executeScript('alert = function(){};');
    driver.executeScript('confirm = function(){};');
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood correctly you would like to close any of alerts appers on page, so you can try to use this class in your code

```
UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.class
```

see also this post [org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772793/org-openqa-selenium-unhandledalertexception-unexpected-alert-open)

Comment: Hi, I am using nodejs. So i'm not able to use this source, thanks anyways.