# Unexpected Alert

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know how to handle alerts but when they come unexpectedly then I am not able to handle them and my script failed. When these alert comes, there is no exception and script keeps on running in background without performing any action. I want handle any unexpected alert thrown by application when my script is running.

I will be very thankful if you share your ways to handle an unexpected alert.

Comment: Dont know what exactly u want. You can use webdriverwait

Comment: We all know how to handle alert when it is known where it is coming. If we don't know where alert will come how that can be handled. I want to make a customised exception handler which can deal with any alert during the script.

Comment: Have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772793/org-openqa-selenium-unhandledalertexception-unexpected-alert-open

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
DesiredCapabilities capablity = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
     capablity .setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
     driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capablity);
```

Comment: My script is on IE. Can I use this in IE driver also?

Comment: Ok. @GouravSinha carry on then. If my answer helps you please upvote :)

Comment: We all know how to handle alert when it is known where it is coming. If we don't know where alert will come how that can be handled. I want to make a customised exception handler which can deal with any alert during the script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154762/discussion-between-iamsankalp89-and-gourav-sinha).