# How to handle the window modal dialog box in Internet Explorer using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate a scenario where I am encountering a window modal dialog box. Please let me know how to automate this situation? I just want to know how to click the highlighted OK button on the popup appearing? Please suggest

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: Tried this as well but hard luck. The control was not switching to the alert box so it wasn't able to click OK button

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: Please Enter a Search Criteria.

Comment: Please check this is the exception I am facing

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772793/org-openqa-selenium-unhandledalertexception-unexpected-alert-open) is of any help.

Comment: Just did the same as the above one Mate

Answer (score 1):

You can also send keyboard events to press enter key as soon as pop up is active
Pressing enter key is as equivalent as clicking OK button

Make use of Robot class in java

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
```

Comment: Tried by implementing Robot class but its not working here

Comment: try adding delay statements in between

`Robot r = new Robot();`
`r.delay(500);`
`r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`
`r.delay(500);`
`r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)`
`r.delay(500);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by using JavascriptExecutor. It always works if we fail to find element using findelement method

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to handle this issue.

DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);

d = new FirefoxDriver(dc);

then implemented the alert code in try catch block

```
try
    {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        System.out.println("Alert data: " + alertText);
        alert.accept();
    }
    catch (UnhandledAlertException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```